# building curl 7.46.0 on windows without cmd

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, curl

`curl` being *new* to me, I am figuring out an easier way to compile it on *Windows*. I've managed to find a good documentation explaining *in layman's terms* all the steps, however this doc is based on  `curl-7.9.6`.

It was simpler since `curllib.dsw` which is the ***Visual Studio Project file*** for `curllib` was found in folder `curl-7.9.6\lib`. So building it was resulting in `libcurl.dll` **+** `libcurl.lib`

Unfortunately this project file is no more in the latest version `7.46.0`, and I would not like to mess around using other techniques I am not familiar with, compiler other than `msvc` (e.g MinGw), and if possible without resorting to `cmd`.

I have already done some researches online before posting this thread, but we never know maybe someone has written on this topic *very simple documentation that everyone could understand and willing to share it publicly* to get both the static *library file* and *DLL* (raised just above) **or** have found a way to get back the project file (`.dsw`) in the latest release which will a priori be straightforward to compile using ***Visual Studio 2013 (v120)***

Best

Comment: You can build curl on the command line with `nmake`, using only the tools that come with Visual C++. You don't need mingw. Did you read `winbuild/BUILD.WINDOWS.txt`?

Comment: @isanae: thanks for your feedback. I've read it indeed, reason why I've mentioned in the thread title `... without cmd` as the `.dsw` file was relatively quicker and easier. But if there are no alternatives, I would have to resort to `cmd` from the doc.

Comment: Your title says "without cmd", but your question says that you want to avoid other compilers. If there's no project files and you don't want to use the command line, you'll have to wait for someone else to build binaries for you. By the way, as a programmer, you should be able to start a VS command prompt, `cd` to the right place and type `nmake /f Makefile.vc`.

Comment: @owner What do you mean that the solution is not up to date. What matters is that it used the latest version of source code to build the library. It does not matter if the output file is named `curl-7.9.6` instead of `curl-7.46.0`, it will still be version `7.46.0`. The output file can be named `potato` and it can still be what you want.

Comment: @isanae: I am testing a code establishing a connexion on `cnn.com` but my the console screen does not return any data. could it be attributable to the different `dll` and `lib` used from builds folder (`ipv6-sspi-winssl`;`ipv6-sspi-winssl-ob-lib`)? I've used the built files from `ipv6-sspi-winssl`) in my sample, fyi. Maybe it's worth posting a new thread.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic:In the documentation I initially considered, the author sugested in `2002` to build `curllib.dsw` found in the `version curl-7.9.6.zip`. To avoid misunderstanding, `curllib.dsw` is not or at least no more found in the latest version I've downloaded today. This is the reason why I was looking for an alternative idea, but I finally end up using `cmd Shell` commands to get both `libcurl.lib` && `libcurl.dll`.