# Printing webpage to console via CURL.h

Tags: c++, curl, console

In the wake of a *previous thread* [Building curl 7.46.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283949/building-curl-7-46-0-on-windows-without-cmd), I've tested the below sample code which does compile without errors, but does not print anything on my console.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <curl/curl.h>  

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;  
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init(); 
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.cnn.com/");    
        system("pause");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* always cleanup */     curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }   
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Is this result due to the setup adopted while installing `libcurl`? As a matter of fact, to get `libcurl.dll` and `libcurl.lib` I've used:

**1** - *(release mode)* : `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll VC=12`

**2** - *(debug mode)*   : `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll VC=12 DEBUG=yes`

Best,

Expectation: Something like

[image]

**[EDIT]** : *Valid Code*

```
#include<string>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <curl/curl.h>  

int main(void)
{
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    CURLcode res;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://edition.cnn.com/");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    system("pause");
}
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic: Please refer to the edited regarding my expectation. Contents of the console should reflect current `cnn.com` page. Hope it helps

Comment: You need more error handling than this. Right now, you don't know whether `curl_easy_init()` or `curl_easy_perform()` is failing. Add output in either case. Use `curl_easy_getinfo()` to check for the http code. Some websites require a correct referer, user-agent, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation at

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

suggests, you need to specify a callback function that will write the
html to some buffer. Then, you can use that buffer to print the
contents. Here is how you do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

static size_t getHtmlCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *ptr)
{
    // Cast ptr to std::string pointer and append contents to that string
    ((std::string*)ptr)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string htmlBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.cnn.com/");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, getHtmlCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &htmlBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(CURLE_OK == res)
        {
            std::cout << htmlBuffer << std::endl;
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the write function defaults to printing to stdout (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html and http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html)

Comment: @randomusername Yes, he just wants to print it for now but my guess is that he will want to do something with the received html later.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic: thanks for the suggestion. however there's a slight operand type issue at `std::cout << htmlBuffer << std::endl`.

Comment: @owner `std::string` object can surely be printed using `std::cout`. Maybe the compiler error is misleading. I forgot to mention you need to include the header that contains `std::string`. See the updated answer.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic: sure. missing `#include` was responsible to it. Unfortunately output screen still blank. has it been tested before posting?

Comment: @owner Of course. I've tested it using a prebuilt libcurl i downloaded from the web. This code works. Did you put libcurl DLL in the same directory as your exe file? Can you step into it with a debugger or put print statements to see what function call fails?

Comment: @MarkoPopovic. ok... sure `dll` is in the same directory otherwise you get error msg box. I 've put break point and realised that the `buffer` was empty for some reasons. Then I merely updated `http`. Thus I trust your code is valid, and I 've also edited a shorter one without  the callback function. Best,

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `libcurl` is failing (i.e. `curl_easy_init` is returning `NULL`).  Sadly, according to http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2009-11/0243.html you have to use a debugger to find out why.